# Creating action for Java Button

Tags: java, swing

I have a Java form written with the Swing library which includes several JTextField objects and a JButton object.

What I would need is, when the user clicks the button, for a method to be called which reads all the values of the JTextField objects and passes them as parameters of another method.

In HTML/JavaScript, this would be similar to:

```
<input type="button" onClick="myMethod()">
```

Where myFunction() would look through all text fields in a form and read the value, then return an array of these values.

Ideas? :)

Thanks

Dario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    JTextField jtf1 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField jtf2 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField jtf3 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField jtf4 = new JTextField(10);
    JButton button = new JButton("Button");

    public Test() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1));
        panel.add(jtf1);
        panel.add(jtf2);
        panel.add(jtf3);
        panel.add(jtf4);

        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){    // add a listener to the button
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  // perform the action when clicked
                String str1 = jtf1.getText();     // get input from text field 1
                String str2 = jtf2.getText();     // get input from text field 2
                String str3 = jtf3.getText();     // get input from text field 3
                String str4 = jtf4.getText();     // get input from text field 4

                // do something with strings
                someMethod(str1, str2, str3, str4);  // pass to someMethod
            }
        });
    }

    private void someMethod(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4){
        // dumb example
        System.out.println(s1 + " " + s2 + " " + s3 + " " + s4);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Test test = new Test();
                test.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                test.pack();
                test.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note: If you want numerical values from the text fields, you should parse the text

Comment: Hi @peeskillet, I get an error telling me that getText() is undefined for type String

Comment: Because it is undefined. Are you trying to use that method with a String? That method is to be used with a text field and returns a String. Hence `String str1 = jtf1.getText();`

Answer (score 2):

Check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

```
b = new Button("Click me");
b.addActionListener(this);



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    numClicks++;
    text.setText("Button Clicked " + numClicks + " times");
}
```

Comment: It might be important to note that `addActionListener(this)` only works if this is referring to a class that implements the ActionListener interface.

Comment: +1 to PakkuDon for pointing this. Thank you !!